# in almost strict mode,img default is inline element or block element?

Tags: html, image

in this article 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

> Nonetheless browser vendors, Mozilla especially, thought this was such
>   a confusing situation that they introduced "almost strict mode". This
>   was defined as strict mode, but with images continuing to be blocks,
>   and not inline elements.

is it right?

i think, in almost strict mode ,img is still a inline element.
if it is a block element,why it wont begin with new line.

Comment: I think an `img` is more akin to `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

sounds right to me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko's_Almost_Standards_Mode

"Almost standards" rendering mode is exactly the same as "standards" mode in all details save one: the layout of images inside table cells is handled as they are in Gecko's "quirks" mode, which is fairly consistent with other browsers, such as Internet Explorer. "